# Query function pulling blanks when a cell value is alphanumeric

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Solved!** Thanks for the help in guiding me in the right direction! What I didn't show, and probably should have, is I am using an array {} for the data portion of the query. That references 24 other sheets in the same doc. Apparently, some of the 'Truck' columns in the other sheets were not set to plain text, which resulted in the error.

I have been using the query function for some time and this is the first time running into this! Thanks so much!

**Sheet1** is sheet w/ data entered by end-users.

**Sheet2** has the following formula:

```
​=IFERROR(QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:N, "SELECT * WHERE D is not null"),0)
```

Note: I must complete this via this method, as the example below is a snapshot of the sheet. It's actually a bit more complicated, but I used this example to simplify the problem. The actual sheet has confidential information so I am unable to share.

**The Problem:**

When a non-numeric value is entered in the 'Truck' column in Sheet1, the query function returns a blank value for that cell. When it's numeric, all is well as illustrated in the image.

The column format is set to 'Automatic'. I tried changing to 'Plain text', however, this results in all 'Truck' column values being blank.

Also worth noting, alphanumeric characters entered in the Routes and Notes columns properly reflects in their respective columns in Sheet2.

Appreciate ANY help as this issue is holding up completion of this project. Thank you[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example spreadsheet, just like the snapshot? It will be easier to help this way.

Comment: I tried to just make a copy of your model, but ended up with the same issue, except reversed: it returns alphanumeric strings just fine, but if it's just numbers it returns blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `QUERY` function does not support mixed formats.**
*(That is you can have either text or numbers)*

> The column format is set to 'Automatic'. I tried changing to 'Plain text', however, this results in all 'Truck' column values being blank.

This should work along with your formula.

```
​=IFERROR(QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:N, "SELECT * WHERE D is not null"),0)
```

*(Note that your `Truck` column appears to be column `C` and not `D`)*

Comment: If you still face issues, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- As marikamitsos mentioned, query doesn't support mixed formats, it's either all values are treated as numbers, or as strings.

#### Solution:

- You can show them all if you set the source column (where you fetch the Truck value) format to **Plain Text** to treat them all as strings.

#### Sample Output:

[image: Output]

[image: output2]

#### Note:

- An extra formula below shows that both source truck (as plain text) and the output from query (automatic) can still be used as integer for calculations (aside from alphanumeric ones).

Comment: Your answer is correct NaziA. I fail to understand though how it is differentiated from mine. Can you elaborate? Did I miss something?

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos, my answer revolves around the format change and specifying it would be done on the source value, yours didn't mention the change of source column to "plain text" (and from what I understand, you explained the issue without any clear solution) so I decided to post one while also showing the difference between the two in a gif/photo which I can't show in a comment under your answer. My apologies if it seems like i'm copying/stealing your solution, it's not my intention.

Comment: *"...yours didn't mention the change of source column to "plain text" (and from what I understand, you explained the issue without any clear solution)"* I thought I had that covered by referring to OP's text *"I tried changing to `Plain text` "*. I guess it wasn't clear enough. Thank you for clarifying that.